# Hash.from_xml double escapes &amp;

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
>> h={:title => "hi &amp; mv288" }
=> {:title=>"hi &amp; mv288"}
>> h.to_xml
=> "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<hash>\n  <title>hi &amp;amp; mv288</title>\n</hash>\n"
>> Hash.from_xml h.to_xml
=> {"hash"=>{"title"=>"hi & mv288"}}
```

If you notice line#2 and #4, the `&amp;` characters in the title value became & after
a series of Hash.to_xml and from_xml method calls.

Is there any way to prevent Hash.from_xml from converting `&amp;` into &.

Comment: In my local test, `Hash.from_xml h.to_xml` gives me the original result `{:title => "hi &amp; mv288"}`......

Comment: emm... I am using jruby-1.5.2/jdk1.6.0_21. Which version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We switched the xml parser to Nokogiri to resolve this issue.

Add this line in your environment.rb

```
ActiveSupport::XmlMini.backend = 'Nokogiri'
```

You will have to have  nokogiri gem installed though. If you need a pure
java implementation of nokogiri, check this out.
https://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri/wiki/pure-java-nokogiri-for-jruby

The installation command is,

```
gem install nokogiri --pre
```

You may also use `LibXml` as XmlMiini.backend to resolve this issue.